# Como apagar dados Modal Bootstrap na segunda vez - ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-3, html5-audio

Quando eu abro Modal na segunda vez, o elemento de áudio continua o mesmo.

Já fiz upload de áudio novo e ainda continua o áudio antigo.

Por favor segue abaixo o meu código.

```
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Voice )
        <br />
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Voice, new { @class = "form-control", @type = "file" })
    </div>
```

Html5 Audio:

```
    <audio controls style="width: 400px;">
        <source src="@Url.Action("StreamUploadedSong")" type="audio/mp3" />
        Your browser does not support the audio element.
    </audio>
```

Javascript:

```
    $(function () {

        $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
        $("a[data-modal]").on("click", function (e) {
            //hide dropdown if any (this is used wehen invoking modal from link in bootstrap dropdown )
            //$(e.target).closest('.btn-group').children('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown('toggle');

            $('#myModalContent').load(this.href, function () {
                $('#myModal').modal({
                    //backdrop: 'static',
                    keyboard: true
                }, 'show');

                //bindForm(this);
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
```

O problema é:

```
public FileStreamResult StreamUploadedSong() // não entra aqui na segunda vez com modal bootstrap
{
}
```

Na segunda vez ele deveria entrar ação Public *StreamUploadedSong* ()

Porque não está trabalhando certo ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isso acontece porque a src que você define url já foi carregada, ao abrir novamente a modal, você não está recarregando o objeto do player ou seu conteúdo, apenas exibindo novamente na tela do usuário.

Atribua um identificador ao seu elmento Audio:

```
 <audio id="audioPlayer" controls style="width: 400px;">
    <source src="@Url.Action("StreamUploadedSong")" type="audio/mp3" />
    Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

E após abrir a modal execute o método load(), isso deve ajudar:

```
   $(function () {

    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
    $("a[data-modal]").on("click", function (e) {
        //hide dropdown if any (this is used wehen invoking modal from link in bootstrap dropdown )
        //$(e.target).closest('.btn-group').children('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown('toggle');

        $('#myModalContent').load(this.href, function () {
            $('#myModal').modal({
                //backdrop: 'static',
                keyboard: true
            }, 'show');

            $("#audioPlayer").load();

            //bindForm(this);
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```